# How to display truncated text?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

Often, a text item is too long to fit the screen, and it gets truncated with three dots (like this: `…`). How can I access the hidden part of the text?

(I tried turning the phone to rotate the display, but it seems to not be a feature of this phone.)

(Sorry for the newbie post. I searched Google and this forum but failed to find anything relevant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-rotation can be enabled in the settings: `Settings > Display > Screen rotation`. Turning the phone then displays text fully.